# can't read serial port buffer in virtual box guest ubuntu and xubuntu machine using pyserial

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, virtual-machine, pyserial

i'm trying to communicate with a serial port in ubuntu guest machine using pyserial, and host being windows 7.

This serial port is enabled by the usb driver in ubuntu, so i just have to enable the usb device in the virtual machine setup.

I'm able to communicate and see response using screen program, but using pyserial i can't see the response, but i'm able to issue commands.

Note that the same pyserial code works in normal ubuntu, without being a virtual machine guest, and also when i restart it works for the first time.

the code i use to receive from buffer is this

```
def serialExecuteCommand(serialPort, command):

serialPort.write(command + '\r\n')
out = ''
time.sleep(1)
while serialPort.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += serialPort.read(1)
return out
```

i'm creating the serial port using this configuration, that i tested and worked on hyperterminal in windows for the same serial port.

```
serialPort = serial.Serial(
    port= port,
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
```

can i do this another way, just to get the response, instead of using pyserial, since the screen tool functions correctly?

**UPDATE 1**

After using the serial port with pyserial for a specific device, the stty settings get changed

```
speed 57600 baud; line = 0;
eof = ^A; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl ixoff ixany -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-icanon -echo -echoe
```

and when is not working to

```
speed 57600 baud; line = 0;
eof = ^A; min = 0; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

tried to do `stty /dev/ttyACM0` sane, and reset to the original

**UPDATE 2**

Lol, this is an hack solution, i was able to get always the response from the serial port, if cat the device file before creating the serial port object with pyserial, and then terminating the cat process after the creation of the object.

Can somebody explain why, after all this time, this works this way????

Comment: Is the baudrate setting correct when you initialize the `serial.Serial`-object?

Comment: yes, i check that value using the stty command tool.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You have two returns for `last_received`  but only one function definition. Is something missing? Please fix that in the question.

Comment: yes, you are right msvalkon, that was some hack i made before, trying to get it to work, i already changed to the correct one.

Comment: Finally, are your pyserial and python versions similar?

Comment: My pyserial version is 2.5, and the python version is 2.7.3

Comment: Try updating to pyserial 2.7 and see if it helps.

Comment: updated to 2.7 but no avail:/

Comment: keep in mind, sometimes it works, like 1/30 of the time ... frustrating, non-deterministic

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty check the port options